# Styles in Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: style, arcgis-portal

is there any possibility to save style of layers and pop-ups designed in Portal for ArcGIS? If not, what are your best way to apply same style for layers and their pop-ups for new-published layer? Is there any clever shortcut?